# What if I don't kill the Enthralled Wizards during the Morokei quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm searching for the Staff of Magnus.  I seem to have found it, because I've walked into a room with a guy trapped in a barrier by two Enthralled Wizards.

[Not being a total idiot](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NiceJobBreakingItHero), I decided to poke around a bit before doing anything rash. I was able to sneak around to the exit door and get a cutscene from Savos explaining who the Enthralled Wizards are.  Great, now I know a little bit more, at least.  The wizards are holding back something big, scary, and evil.

I attempted to pickpocket the wizards, just to see what would happen.  Turns out when you pickpocket them, they stop casting.  Which means Morokei becomes free yet non-hostile and the wizards are both alive.

Morokei passively stood there while I killed him.  It wasn't even a battle, it was like slaughtering an unresistant lamb.

So now I've got the Staff of Magnus.  **Did I break the rest of the quest?  Will there be problems later on with events not being triggered because of this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll be fine. You found a bug in the quest scripting, is all. The intended behaviour is that you have to disrupt/aggro and fight the Enthralled Wizards, which then releases Morokei, but there's nothing in the quest or rest of the game that relies on actually killing them. The rest of the quest triggers off of killing Morokei and getting the Staff.

Though, you did miss a pretty sweet boss fight.

Comment: I guess I'll reload.  Boss fights are cool.